# Boot Android disabling display

Tags: boot

I know that android doesnot have a login prompt like linux and only has diplay to interact with the user.
Still I want to boot Android without any display and I expect only the UART console prints of Andriod.
Does Android source code has this implementation or do I have to customise Android for this specific requirement ?

Comment: Well this is a nice idea..Good Luck.